# Maximum Height 2-3 Tree

Tags: java, arrays, tree, traversal

To find the maximum height of a 2-3 Tree, can you keep traversing from the root node to its left child node, going all the way down until you run into a leaf?

This is fact: Since all leaf-nodes are on the same height, the lowest leaf at any point is the maximum height of the tree. (All leaf-nodes are on the same level).

If you keep going left do you always reach the bottom?

Comment: It will depend upon the type of tree also...

Comment: How so? I mentioned 2-3 Tree.. what do you mean?

Comment: Seems I mis-interpreted your question. But what exactly you meant by that 2-3 tree

Comment: http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/DepTypedProg/Notes/2-3-Tree.png

Comment: One of those bad boys. The insertion method is mildly tricky so unless you're familiar with that.. not sure if you can help... but I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 2-3 Trees are balanced, which means each sub-tree (Left,Center,Right) will contain close to same amount of data - considering this statement, we can assume that traversing till the leaf-node (in any of the sub-tree) will give you the height of the 2-3 tree.

Owing to the balance of the tree, we can also say that all operations tend to be `O(lg n)`.

**UPDATE**:

> A 2-3 Tree is a null tree (zero nodes) or a single node tree (only one node) or a 
>   multiple node tree with the following properties:
>
> 1. Each interior node has two or three children
> 2. Each path from the root to a leaf has the same length.

From CS dept, IISc: http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/node118.html

Comment: True story. To obtain the height of the tree, I'm guessing you can keep traversing to each node's *left* child until you hit a leaf. That leaf must be the height of the tree. Would this work?

Comment: Yes, that would give you the height.

Comment: I'm kind of wondering if there's any scenario where a left leaf node (at the bottom) wouldn't exist. Please look at the picture I posted in the above comment (it's a link) to help visualize.

Comment: So you can alllllways go left can't you?

Comment: Would a left traversal work on all trees, all the time, no matter the data values inserted?

Comment: Thank you, but I'm more focusing on how to get to a leaf. Because I'm just looking to start from the first node, and *keep going left*. If I keep going left, I have to hit a leaf, no?

Comment: I mean, not traversing right, not search to see if a node has children, etc, etc. I mean, just go left. If it's not a leaf, go left again. Until I hit a leaf. I'm wondering if I would inevitably hit a leaf if I keep going left.

Comment: Yes, note the second property. **Each path from root to leaf has same length** - so just going left all the way will work. You will invariably hit the leaf - if not it's not a properly formed 2-3 tree.

Comment: Can you store zero in a 2-3 tree? It would have to be the verrry left leaf node, correct? Assuming all the values in the tree are positive.